# Configure JDK in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, windows, maven, visual-studio-code

My project is Maven-based. To execute the Maven-Tasks, a JDK (not just a JRE) ist necessary. I dont want to define the path to the JDK in environment variables (such as JAVA_HOME or JDK_HOME), because that affects other software too. So I set "java.home": "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin" in settings.json and Maven is happy. But VSC tells me "This path is not pointing to a JDK. Try remove the "bin" from the path.". But if I remove the \bin part, Maven complaints about only having a JRE, not a JDK. With \bin on the other side, code completion in the editors does not work anymore. Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you invoking maven? Are you using the maven plugin from microsoft?

Comment: Yes, I use Microsofts plugin. I've tried both, by plugin (i.e. Custom... sprign-boot:run) and in the Terminal (mvn spring-boot:run). When I change the Environment Variable JDK_HOME in the Terminal to the ../bin Directory,it works.

Comment: Perhaps you can try the configuration first in the environment variable （ JAVA_HOME or JDK_HOME) to see if it works,If it's ok, it's probably the java.home path configuration error

Comment: Problem solved. I suppose, it was an update of VSC that did it. But not really sure. I also found a checkbox-property in Maven settings: "Terminal: Use JavaHome" which says "If this value is true, and if the setting java.home has a value, then the environment variable JAVA_HOME will be set to the value of java.home when a new terminal window is created". I checked it. Just to be sure.